# Prevent non thread-safe method to be used in multithreaded context

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is there a way to throw an exception when a user tries to use a non thread-safe method of a class in a multithreaded context? I guess the issue is mostly to detect that multiple threads are trying to use the method. Or, is there a "not_synchronous" keyword/tag I could use on the function declaration?

Comment: For about the same amount of work, you could probably make the method thread-safe.

Comment: @Alex For probably less work ;-)

Comment: Why not make that method thread-safe if you are really worried about multi-thread access?

Comment: declare it as synchronized for starters? ;)

Comment: It's a given that we have Java core library classes that are not thread-safe by design, so Frank's question is of interest.  That said, as all have pointed out - you may loose the performance advantage by making the check.  You can be safe(r), or you can be fast(er), but you can't have it all.

Comment: The situation is that I have a class that I know is not thread-safe, and I don't have time to make it thread-safe right now. It's ok with the rest of the project, but I was asked in code review to document, and I thought that there might be a (temporary) way to have a stronger check than just documenting - till next month I have the cycles to make it thread safe.

Comment: No. It is actually very tricky to synchronize given the semantics of what I'm implementing. It's not even clear that it makes sense to have multiple threads work on this data structure concurrently.

Comment: "Thread-safe" and "concurrent" don't necessarily mean the same thing. You can make something thread-safe by protecting the underlying data structure to make sure only one thread at a time is working on it, e.g. by putting a lock on it.

Comment: To answer the other part of your question -- no, there's nothing built-in that will help you here. Just make sure the fact that it isn't thread-safe is mentioned prominently in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, no.  If you are detecting that multiple threads are using a method, then chances are you will have to be using thread-safe collections and the like.  If you are doing all that then you might as well have to make the method itself thread-safe.

Comment: An alternative (possibly weak) option is the strategy used by the standard collections' iterators.

Comment: Interesting idea but there's no guarantee that it would work however @assylias. No guarantee that you would hit the race.

Answer (score 3):

You could check whether the method is already in use before allowing a thread to run it - but that is not very different from using a lock (note: my example is not reentrant):

```
private static final AtomicBoolean used = new AtomicBoolean();

public static void unsafe() throws InterruptedException {
    if(!used.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    //do you stuff
    used.set(false);
}
```

Comment: Much saner than my example :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Gray's answer: suppose you wanted to do this (detect when a method is being used by multiple threads). A naive (and incorrect) implementation of this might look like:

```
volatile boolean methodBeingUsed = false;
public void doSomething() {
  if (methodBeingUsed) throw new IllegalStateException("You can't do that!");
  try {
    methodBeingUsed = true;
    // do something...
  } finally {
    methodBeingUsed = false;
  }
}
```

Well, OK... but two threads could both get past the first `if (methodBeingUsed)` check and enter the critical section at the same time. So now maybe we try adding a lock to protect the `methodBeingUsed` flag:

```
Lock methodLock = new ReentrantLock();
volatile boolean methodBeingUsed = false;
public void doSomething() {
  try {
    lock.lock();
    if (methodBeingUsed) throw new IllegalStateException("You can't do that!");
    methodBeingUsed = true;
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }

  try {
    // do something...
  } finally {
    try {
      lock.lock();
      methodBeingUsed = false;
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that doSomething() can't recursively call itself. If it can, then you also have to keep track of the calling thread. Add in some more checks to account for other conditions that I'm not thinking of right now, and it's easy to see that the effort spent synchronizing the logic to detect the method being used by multiple threads would be better spent just making the method thread-safe to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if your goal is to determine that "multiple threads are trying to use this method," and you're not constraining that to "multiple methods... at the same time" - then (forgive me) Alex's code can be adapted nicely:

1. Change `methodBeingUsed` to `threadOwningMethod`, and set it to the thread instead of `true`.
2. You don't need to clear it at the end - save those lock/unlock steps.  Once it's owned, it's owned (capitalist pig!!).
3. `threadOwningMethod` can be checked up-front to see if it matches the current thread (A-OK) or not (throw exception) without having to incur the lock.  If it's not set (null), then you incur a one-time hit: check/lock/check&set/unlock; this is safe because `threadOwningMethod` is marked volatile.

Comment: From Frank's last comment, this probably isn't what he's looking for.